# Android auto DHU - Failed to read from transport - disconnect. Exiting

Tags: android, emulation, android-auto

When I try to connect the android auto DHU, following error occurs.
before running the DHU, I have done following steps.

1. connected USB with mobile
2. android auto app is running
3. adb forward tcp:5277 tcp:5277
4. ./../extras/google/auto/desktop-head-unit

4th step getting an error :-

desktop-head-unit[54345:3905939] 00:05:51.597 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
Connecting over ADB to localhost:5277...connected.

> Failed to read from transport - disconnect. Exiting...

Android Studio Version : 2.2.3
Mobile : nexus 5
Android Version : 6.0.1

Please suggest.

Answer (score 10):

You should probably verify if you started the head unit server from your phone (Developer mode should be enabled on the Android Auto app)

[image]

then, 
Open a terminal and type `adb forward tcp:5277 tcp:5277`.

Afterwards start the DHU :

```
cd <sdk>/extras/google/auto/
```

`./desktop-head-unit` (Windows : `desktop-head-unit.exe`)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is need to start the Head Unit Server from android auto companion app. After that Im able to connect and see the DHU in mac.

./../extras/google/auto/desktop-head-unit
Connecting over ADB to localhost:5277...connected.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#running-dhu) :

> Warning: There is currently a known issue where the DHU can crash on
>   startup when connecting to Android Auto 4.7. To work around this
>   issue, we recommend that you temporarily downgrade to Android Auto 4.6
>   until a fix can be released in Android Auto 4.8.

Source : https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#running-dhu

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart adb like the command "adb kill-server" and then set the tcp again.
Check if you started the head unit from the companion app

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other replies, the [head unit server](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/testing/) needs to be running on your device.  If you have multiple devices attached (for example, an emulator and a physical device) you may be attempting to connect to a device without the head unit server running.  Try disconnecting all other devices and reconnecting.